# Python base64 encode/decode removing DPI information from image

Tags: python, image-processing, base64, python-imaging-library

I need to send an image from the server to the client.

The image on the server has the DPI information. But after encode and decode the image in base64, the DPI is lost.

And the DPI information is required on the client side.

```py
from PIL import Image
import io
import base64

def image_to_base64(image, type):

    type = 'jpeg' if type == 'jpg' else type

    with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
        image.save(buffer, type)
        return base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue()).decode()

def base64_to_image(image_base64):

    return Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(image_base64)))

image = Image.open("tmp29ypubt0.jpeg")

print('\nOriginal image: ' + str(image.info))

b64 = image_to_base64(image, 'jpeg')
new_image = base64_to_image(b64)

print('b64 image: ' + str(new_image.info) + '\n')
```

The results (Python 3.7.9):

```
$ python3 test_b64.py 

Original image: {'jfif': 257, 'jfif_version': (1, 1), 'dpi': (600, 600), 'jfif_unit': 1, 'jfif_density': (600, 600)}
b64 image: {'jfif': 257, 'jfif_version': (1, 1), 'jfif_unit': 0, 'jfif_density': (1, 1)}
```

I believe that the DPI information is lost in the encode step, because I tested any ways to decode it and in all of them I didn't get the DPI information.

How can I encode an image using base64 and keep the DPI information ?

Comment: If you want to send the exact contents of the JPEG file over the network without any changes, try using file system functions to load the data instead of the PIL package - that package is probably processing the data in ways you don't want.

Comment: @Kryten the problem is not the PIL, I've already tested it. The problem is after the `image_to_base64(image, 'jpeg')`

Comment: Since the base64-encoded data that you're receiving is missing information, either **(1)** `image.save(buffer, type)` is dropping that information when you encode the base64 data, or ***(2)*** `Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(image_base64)))` is ignoring that information when you decode the base64 data. These are both routines from the PIL package (via the Image object) - hence my conclusion that the PIL package is doing something you don't expect.

Comment: Just do it yourself with [`base64.b64encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode)